# Title case in C# using split()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a simple program that lets the user input a sentence and it gets converted to title case. The first letter in each word is made capital. When it runs I don't get any errors, but it doesn't convert. Can someone let me know what I am missing? Thanks in advance!

This is my .cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (!Page.IsValid)
        {
            string sentence = phrase.Text;
            String[] sentenceArray = sentence.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < sentenceArray.Length; i++)
            {
                sentenceArray[i] = sentenceArray[i].Substring(0,      1).ToUpper() + sentenceArray[i].Substring(1).ToLower();
            }
            phrase.Text = String.Join(" ", sentenceArray);
        }
    }
  }
  }
```

If needed here is the HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Convert to Title Case</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <p>
        Enter a phrase and click the Title Case button.</p>
        <p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="phrase" runat="server" /> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="letterValidator"
                runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required field" ControlToValidate="phrase" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="progress" runat="server" Value="**********" />
            <asp:Button ID="convertToTitleCase" runat="server" Text="Title Case" />
        </p>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As an aside, use events instead of `Page_Load` to handle your button's click event. That's much clearer and less error-prone.

Comment: Also, you could use `textInfo.ToTitleCase`: `TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo; phrase.Text = textInfo.ToTitleCase(phrase.Text);`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is executed only when page is **not** valid:

```
if (!Page.IsValid)
```

And your only validator is

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="letterValidator"
            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required field" ControlToValidate="phrase" />
```

So, just remove the `if (!Page.IsValid)` condition and it will work correctly.

**P.S.:** And as it has been already pointed in another answer, you will have to be careful with `Substring`. At least use [`String.Split(string, StringSplitOptions)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to avoid index exception when someone enters string with two sequential spaces.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of comments:

1. `if (!Page.IsValid)` - are you sure that's what you meant? Maybe `if (Page.IsValid)` is more like it.
2. `sentenceArray[i] = sentenceArray[i].Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + sentenceArray[i].Substring(1).ToLower();` - what will happen if `sentenceArray` is empty (possible unless `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` is given to `String.Split`)? - Either add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as a parameter to `String.Split` - or add a check here.